# User-Agent replacement for calls from cmd

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, user-agent

On the Windows 7 cmd, I call a program which needs a http GET. Unfortunately, the proxy denies the request because the User-Agent is "Java..." and not the one of Internet Explorer or Mozilla. Is there any way to manipulate the http request?

I tried to use Fiddler, but actually, I cannot see the request in Fiddler and the change of User-Agent does not work.

Comment: Powershell may work. Have you tried that?

Comment: @LPChip Sorry, could you be more specific?

Comment: PowerShell has a com-applet that can be used to access data from the internet. PowerShell is far more powerful so it is possible your proxy will allow it, or it has settings to specify the User-Agent. Have you looked into Powershell?

Comment: Powershell is huge. I have no idea where to start looking. And I am not sure that I made myself clear. I am just starting a third-party command line tool and want to manipulate its http calls to use another user agent.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. I don't think its possible though.

Comment: In the past, I had successfully used Fiddler, but either this depends on the command line or on the changing proxy values, now it does not work anymore.